# how do i make a variable unique

Tags: tcl

How do I make a variable unique in TCL?

Example:

```
exec echo $msgBody - /tmp/Alert_Notify_Work.$$
exec cat /home/hci/Alert.txt -- /tmp/Alert_Notify_Work.$$
```

This does not work; I am trying to make the variable `Alert_Notify_Work` unique.

Answer (score 5):

It's best to use a pre-existing library for this. Tcllib has a fileutil package that implements tempfiles:

```
set filename [fileutil::tempfile Alert_Notify_Work.]
```

Answer (score 2):

`$$` is not valid Tcl syntax, and Tcl will parse that line before the shell sees it.  But there is a Tcl command to retrieve the pid: `pid`.  I usually rely on the current time and the pid for uniqueness.

I assume `msgBody` is a Tcl variable, and the `-` and `--` in your commands should be `>` and `>>` respectively.

option 1

```
set filename /tmp/Alert_Notify_Work.[clock seconds].[pid]
exec echo $msgBody > $filename
exec cat /home/hci/Alert.txt >> $filename
```

or, Tcl only with just a few more lines:

```
set f_out [open /tmp/Alert_Notify_Work.[clock seconds].[pid] w]
puts $f_out $msgBody
set f_in  [open /home/hci/Alert.txt r]
fcopy $f_in $f_out
close $f_in
close $f_out
```

Comment: +1: I'd use `clock clicks` instead myself (or `file tempfile` in 8.6) but what you suggest works.